# What is the most basic operators of reactive extension?

Tags: reactive-programming

Since many operators in reactive extension seem like it could be fabricated from other operators, such as `Min` `Max` `Sum` and any aggregate function could be made from `Reduce`

So like boolean algebra have basic operation `AND` and `NOT` (or using `OR` instead of `AND`) and all other could be fabricated from these basic. I want to know the most basic operators of reactive extensions, and if possible, the hierarchy tree of operator

Is there any available?

Comment: You really should read about monads. That's really what the reactive extensions are based on. That would explain the most basic operators.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have read about monad and also using Linq for years. I think I am familiar with the concept. But as I said, I think this system somehow have hierarchy of basicality, some operator actually derived from other, like most of operator that collapse stream to one value is most likely `reduce` in some form. But reactive is extend this concept to cover time. So it seem like there was more additional basic operators and more complex hierarchy structure. That's what I want to understand the picture